# Unable to get lock on /var/lib/dpkg/lock when trying to execute $: salt \* pkg.install vim

Tags: python, salt-stack

I am using salt stack for development of an SCM. I have successfully connected the master to the minion and the following command works successfully.

```
$: salt \* test.ping
```

Now, I am trying to execute the following command.

```
$: salt \* pkg.install vim
```

To install vim on the minion using the master, when I execute this command on the master, I am getting the following error

```
[INFO    ] User sudo_user1 Executing command pkg.install with jid 20140910191537152620
[DEBUG   ] Command details {'tgt_type': 'glob', 'jid': '20140910191537152620', 'tgt': '*', 'ret': '', 'user': 'sudo_user1', 'arg': ['vim'], 'fun': 'pkg.install'}
[INFO    ] Starting a new job with PID 5762
[INFO    ] Executing command "dpkg-query --showformat='${Status} ${Package} ${Version} ${Architecture}\n' -W" in directory '/home/cybage'
[INFO    ] Executing command ['apt-get', '-q', '-y', '-o', 'DPkg::Options::=--force-confold', '-o', 'DPkg::Options::=--force-confdef', 'install', 'vim'] in directory '/home/user1'
[ERROR   ] Command ['apt-get', '-q', '-y', '-o', 'DPkg::Options::=--force-confold', '-o', 'DPkg::Options::=--force-confdef', 'install', 'vim'] failed with return code: 100
[ERROR   ] output: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
[INFO    ] Executing command "dpkg-query --showformat='${Status} ${Package} ${Version} ${Architecture}\n' -W" in directory '/home/cybage'
[INFO    ] Returning information for job: 20140910191537152620
[DEBUG   ] Decrypting the current master AES key
[DEBUG   ] Loaded minion key: /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pem
```

Both master and minion are Ubuntu 14.04. Please let me know if anyone has faced a similar issue or am I missing something here. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to figure out what was wrong.

I started salt-master using the following command

```
shwetabhs@shwetabhs-master:/etc/salt# sudo salt-master -l debug
```

Instead, it should be started from root

```
root@shwetabhs-master:/etc/salt# salt-master -l debug
```

Starting the master from root solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this means another process is already doing something with your package manager, hence the lock notification. Does apt-get install vim work on the command line?

Do you get this error every time you run this salt command?

Comment: I had exactly the same thought so I executed the following command a number of times, just to check if another program is running. ps ax | grep apt-get There was no other process running in the back ground. And yes, I get this every time I execute the command. I am not sure if salt stack is executing multiple apt-get in parallel.

Also, when installing manually on the minion using command - sudo apt-get innstall vim, it works perfect. I have a base machine Ubuntu 14.04 and an vmdk of Ubuntu 14.04 as my minion.

Comment: Thanks Utah_Dave, I was able to figure out the problem. I have posted the answer below. Thanks for your help.